# React Scripts fails to compile

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, github-pages

I've found a bunch of somewhat related answers but can't seem to fix so far...

Bit new to React (and I'm tirrred) so have no clue - I've created a new React app with create-react-app, then added the Github Pages bits in package.json per [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#github-pages).

On `npm run build` it's failing to compile. Error below. things I've tried:

- Removing and reinstalling node_modules
- clearing npm cache
- destroying and rebuilding proj from scratch

---

```
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react' in '/Users/Mac/Sites/cintacks/src'

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cintacks@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cintacks@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Mac/.npm/_logs/2017-06-14T19_52_07_541Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cintacks@0.1.0 predeploy: `npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cintacks@0.1.0 predeploy script
```

Comment: is the `homepage` property set correctly (to the public address of the github pages website)? also, does that work locally, but not remotely? can you bypass this issue by using `env CI= npm run build` in your deployment descriptor (probably *main.yml*)?

Answer (score 0):

Given the current situation, I'd try:

- Inspecting `/Users/Mac/.npm/_logs/2017-06-14T19_52_07_541Z-debug.log`
- Re-installing `create-react-app`
- Running `npm start` and/or `npm run build` without adding the GitHub pages bits

Also:

- Shouldn't you be running `npm run deploy`?
- Take a look at `/Users/Mac/Sites/cintacks/src`. Is there a folder called `react` in there?

Comment: The error log is the same essentially as what I posted above. I managed to fix it... by using yarn instead of npm - posted as an answer. You definitely pointed me in the right direction - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else runs into this issue, I managed to fix this by following the command prompts within create-react-app, rather than their github documentation. In the [docs](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#github-pages), they say to install gh-pages via npm.. but in the command prompt, you're prompted to install via yarn: `yarn add --dev gh-pages` then `yarn run deploy`. Not entirely sure why the difference but it worked with yarn.

Answer (score 0):

If you arrived like me on this post, it might also be completely unrelated to create-react-app itself but to Git and case sensitivity.

As case sensitivity is different on MacOS (case insensitive filesystem) and Unix OS (case sensitive), if you change your filenames with a different case but don't pay attention, it might lead your code to work on Mac while failing when deploying on your server.

A quick fix for all the incorrect filename :

```bash
    # Untrack all of the files
    $ git rm -r --cached . 

    # Add them back to fix the case tracking problem
    $ git add .
```